# Vis.js focus on the Current Time (Red Line)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js

How do I alter the Vis.js timeline so that it always focuses on current time ticker (red line) so that I know what's happening right now in the timeline. Depending on how far or what zoom level I have, the timeline should PAN left or right and focus on the current time ticker.

I am thinking about two options here: either have a setInterval() running that updates and focuses on the current time every 15 minutes or have a button on the page that will manually do that.

From my research I have found this so far which is tied to a button and obviously does not work yet:

```
document.getElementById('focusNow').onclick = function() {
      timeline.focus(timeline.currentTime.bar)
          };
```

Comment: Have you considered the streaming data example http://visjs.org/examples/graph2d/15_streaming_data.html

Comment: I think so, that is pretty similar. But, how would I apply that to the timeline instead of Graph2d? I have a vis.js timeline with a timesheet schedule. At any given point of time, the timeline should show who is supposed to work currently.

Comment: Timeline and Graph2d have the same core, and they have many methods in common. You can apply the renderStep function from this streaming data example to the Timeline as is, you only have to replace graph2d.* with myTimeline.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I was able to solve it like this:

```
var refresh = 10000;
timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, data, options);

function updateTimeline(refresh) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var current = new Date();
        timeline.moveTo(current);
        updateTimeline(refresh)
    }, refresh);
}
updateTimeline(refresh);
```

The updateTimeline function runs every 10 seconds and moves the timeline so that the current time is centered (using the moveTo() function), thus keeping the red line centered. Once my project is finished I will update with a github link.